# HTTP Bad Request Debugging Methods

Tags: ruby, http, debugging, post

So I'm getting an HTTP Bad Request error when trying a POST to an endpoint. I've been at it for two hours and can't figure out the problem. I've looked at documentation and combed stackoverflow. Help on fixing the code is appreciated, but more importantly, can someone point me to methods for troubleshooting/debugging this myself? A good blog post maybe?

```
require 'logger'
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

def put_into_list(payload) # payload is an array of strings
  logger = Logger.new("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/etc/daily.log", 0, 100 * 1024 * 1024)
  logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

  config = grab_config
  uri = URI("https://website.com/endpoint")
  header = {'Content-Type' => 'text/json'}

  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https',
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
    req.basic_auth config['key'], config['pass']

    payload.each do |entry|
      req.body = entry.to_json
      logger.info("Setting req.body to #{req.body}")

      begin
        res = http.request req
        logger.info("Got response of: #{res}")
        logger.info("Got response body of: #{res.body}")
      rescue => j
        logger.info("Rescuing: #{j}")
        logger.info("Backtrace: #{j.backtrace}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is what my logging file looks like:

```
I, [2017-06-09T08:44:05.616776 #16932]  INFO -- : Setting req.body to "{'prospect':{'email':'test@gmail.com'}}"
I, [2017-06-09T08:44:05.703313 #16932]  INFO -- : Got response of: #<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x2d77aa8>
I, [2017-06-09T08:44:05.704207 #16932]  INFO -- : Got response body of: {"status":{"status":"ERROR","code":"E_UNNOWN","msg":"Unknown error."}}
```

Comment: Do you have a working `cURL` command for the endpoint? (What is it?)

Comment: Make sure you are actually able to connect to the endpoint successfully, before debugging the ruby!

Comment: @TomLord, No I can't connect to the endpoint using `cURL` just tried: `curl -u user:pass https://web.com/endpoint` and I'm pretty sure that I have the right endpoint from the API documentation.

Comment: This is the first thing you need to debug, then. Without knowing how to connect via curl, I have no way to help debug the ruby... If this is a private resource, then maybe try contacting the maintainer for assistance; if it's public then let us know what it is so I can see the documentation for myself!

Comment: @TomLord I figured it out! I did get a connection with cURL successfully, once I had the right cURL request. Once I verified that I realized the problem was with the payload i was sending, it had a goofy syntax that needed to be fixed.